# Error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo()’

Tags: c++

I have the following two files

foobar.h

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

#include <cstring>

class Foo {
public:
  int x;
  Foo(int x);
};
    
class Bar {
public:
  char* name;
  Foo foo;
  Bar(Foo foo);
};

#endif // FOOBAR_H
```

and foobar.cpp

```
#include "foobar.h"

Foo::Foo(int x) {
    // Do something
}

Bar::Bar(Foo foo) {
    // Do something
}
```

Attempting to compile these with `g++ -c foobar.cpp -o foobar.o` results in the following error:

```
foobar.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar::Bar(Foo)’:
foobar.cpp:9:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
 Bar::Bar(Foo foo) {
                 ^
foobar.cpp:5:1: note: candidate: ‘Foo::Foo(int)’
 Foo::Foo(int x) {
 ^~~
foobar.cpp:5:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from foobar.cpp:1:
foobar.h:5:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)’
 class Foo {
       ^~~
foobar.h:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
foobar.h:5:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Foo::Foo(Foo&&)’
foobar.h:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

As far as I understand the output of g++ is that it requires me to have a default constructor for foo. Why? I wish to pass a foo object to the constructor of bar, why would it need to invoke a default constructor anywhere? I do not want to have a no-args constructor anyways, since I NEED that x has a specific user defined value.

Comment: hi, perhaps pass by reference `Bar(Foo &foo)` (to avoid the need to copy the arg)?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with member initializer lists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Passing by reference does not seem to change anything, sadly. Tried that at first too

Comment: You have `Foo` member variable, it has to be initialized. You can initialize before the constructor body will be executed using `Bar::Bar(Foo foo): foo(foo.x)`, or better have a copy-constructor inside `Foo`, so that you can do more reliably ``Bar::Bar(Foo foo): foo(foo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to default construct a `Foo` here:

```
Bar::Bar(Foo foo) {
    // the member variable `foo` would have been default constructed here

    // Do something
}
```

But `Foo` doesn't have a default constructor. One possible solution would be to initialize it in the member initializer list:

```
Bar::Bar(Foo foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) { // now uses the move constructor instead
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I understand the problem now!

Comment: @SimonBusch Great! You're welcome!